# How can I install Ubuntu Server on HP MediaSmart (Model: EX495)?

Tags: server, system-installation

I have no idea how to install server OS. I'm not sure if this device supports 64-bit. If not, where can I download a 32-bit version?

- RAM: 2GB
- HDD: 160GB, 1.5TB and 40GB

The previous owner took all the HDD(s) out of the machine before he sold it to me and I don't have any recovery CD or anything like that.

My friend suggested I look into Ubuntu for my HP MediaSmart Server...

What should I do to install Ubuntu Server on this device?

Comment: If this is the Pentium version, it definitely supports 64bit. In which case all you should need to do is throw in some drives, and create a bootable USB installer for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The article at the following link describes a procedure that worked well for me.

https://dagolav.prestegarden.com/post/instaling-ubuntu-on-the-hp-mediasmart-ex490/

The basic idea is to take the boot disk out of the server and put it in another PC with keyboard and video support. Do the install and then put it back in the MediaSmart Server.

The article refers to Ubuntu 10, but I installed 18.04.1 successfully. I'd add that it's useful to install ssh server and perhaps xRdp for remote access, both of which I've done.

Don't expect zippy performance, it's a pretty underpowered box. Also, as yet it doesn't show all the drives that are physically plugged in. In my case it shows drive 1 and 3, but not 2 and 4.